# list the multiple file in directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to list below multiple file daily so I need the list the file by date should select from system only in file name.

```
ls -lrt test_20160322.csv
```

I am getting error while using below command :-

```
ls -lrt test_${date +"%Y%m%d"}

-bash: ${date +"%Y%m%d"}: bad substitution
```

Comment: `$(date +"%Y%m%d")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change it to:

```
ls -lrt test_$(date +"%Y%m%d")
              ↑              ↑
```

Comment: That's some beautiful arrows right there, just to clarify those are not needed in the actually script.

Comment: @andlrc thanks, that'll be sad if someone thought they should be part of the scrip :) Just noticed that you posted the answer as a comment some seconds before I posted my answer. Please post it and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

Your substitution is wrong you need a command substitution:

```
ls -lrt test_$(date +"%Y%m%d")
```

Please note that I changed `{` and `}` with `(` and `)`.

Also note that command substitutions will undergo [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and should usually be quoted, though in your exact case this will not be the problem.